# Angular 2+ share json config values with all http services

Tags: angular

I have an angular service which reads a json file containing a rest fqdn and rest port ({ "restFqdn":"kuno.dev.net", "restPort":"58085" }). I want share the fqdn and port with all other http services, which get json data from a backend rest server. The fqdn and port are static after being read from the json file, but the json file can contain different values for a particular deployment.

```
@Injectable()
export class FileService {

    private result: Object;
    private restFqdn = '';
    private restPort = '';

    constructor(private http:Http) {

        this.result = this.getConfFile();
        console.log('FileService - constructor: ', this.result)
        this.setFqdn(this.result[0]);
        this.setPort(this.result[1]);

    }

    getConfFile() {
        return this.http.get('json/conf.json')
            .map( (res:Response) => {
                    this.result = res.json();
                    console.log('FileService - getConfFile(): ', this.result)
                    return this.result;
                }
            )
            .catch( error =>
                Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
            );
    };

    setFqdn(value) {
        this.restFqdn = value;
        console.log('FileService - setFqdn(): ', this.restFqdn);
    }

    getFqdn() {
        return this.restFqdn;
    }
```

I am not sure how to share the fqdn and port with my services. I don't really think this is state information, but do I try and use an external library like ngrx/store to do this or is there some other approach that works? This is what I currently have in my RateService.ts:

```
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _fileService: FileService) {

    this._fileService.getConfFile().subscribe (
      data => {
        this.restFqdn = data.restFqdn;
        this.restPort = data.restPort;
        this.rateApi = '/kuno/rate';
        this.rateUrl = 'http://' + this.restFqdn + ':' + this.restPort + this.rateApi;
        console.log('RateService - constructor() - restFqdn: ', this.restFqdn);
        console.log('RateService - constructor() - restPort: ', this.restPort);
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Error - getConfFile failed!';
      }
    );
  }
```

The constructor prints out the correct values from the json file for rest fqdn and rest port. However, when I execute my getRates call, the fqdn and port are undefined. What do I need to do to get the values propagated to getRates()?

```
 getRates(): Observable<any> {

    console.log('RateService - getRates() - getFqdn(): ', this._fileService.getFqdn()); // prints undefined

    return this._http.get(this.rateUrl)
           .do(data => {

                          console.log('RateService: getRates(): ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                       })
           .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What does the constructor for the ratesService look like? Is your FileService being injected into the constructor of the ratesService?

Comment: constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _fileService: FileService) {
 
    this._fileService.getConfFile().subscribe (
      data => {
        this.restFqdn = data.restFqdn;
        this.restPort = data.restPort;
        this.rateApi = '/kuno/rates';
        this.rateUrl = 'http://' + this.restFqdn + ':' + this.restPort + this.rateApi;
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Error - getConfFile failed!';
        this._notifyService.send(this.errorMessage, 30, 'error');
      }
    );
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the following:

```
this.setFqdn(this.result[0]);
this.setPort(this.result[1]);
```

What it does is gets the 0th and 1st element from the array of response and sets it, but seeing at you config.json file, the request is in this format:

```
{ "restFqdn":"kuno.dev.net", "restPort":"58085" }
```

Which isn`t an array.Also why do you need a constructor to make the Call to your config.json file, when you are doing the same in :

```
this._fileService.getConfFile().subscribe (
  data => {
```

All you need to do is following:

Create a simple class, which maps with your config request as below (Not compulsory, but it is a cleaner way to read a Config File):

```
export class ConfigProp {
 restFqdn: string;
 restPort: string;
}
```

In your FileService class try with following changes:

```
@Injectable()
export class FileService {
    result: ConfigProp;
    constructor(private http:Http) {
        }

        getConfFile() {
            return this.http.get('json/conf.json')
                .map( (res:Response) => {
                        this.result = res.json();
                        console.log('FileService - getConfFile(): ', this.result)
                        return this.result;
                    }
                )
                .catch( error =>
                    Observable.throw(error || 'Server error')
                );
        };
}
```

Rest Everything else seems fine.

Also a word of advice. Since the config file is a shared file among different services. You might need to keep it in assets folder, as the folder is meant to contain shared, configurable resources.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the advice on assets folder. I am still missing something because in my service, the fx getRates this.restFqdn is blank. 
getRates(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('RateService - fqdn: ', this.restFqdn); // blank

    return this._http.get(this.rateUrl)
           .do(data => {
                          console.log('RateService: getRates(): ' + JSON.stringify(data))
                       })
           .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: Is getRates method in RateService.ts class?. If yes, then I don`t see any reasons why the code shouldn`t work. In any case, can you share the complete RateService.ts class??